# graphviz visualisation of cluster created with cluster function

Tags: visualization, graphviz

I have a graph which i clustered using the cluster.exe function. The result now has cluster. My problem is: how do I visualise them. My .gv file looks something like this.

```
graph {
node [cluster=-1];
Delete_CAFOR     [cluster=1];
Complete_SACOZ   [cluster=1];
Delete_CAFOR -- Complete_SACOZ   [weight=131533];
Delete_CAFOR -- Trigger_PAREQ    [weight=2386];
Renew_PUTOZ  [cluster=1];
Delete_CAFOR -- Renew_PUTOZ  [weight=260];
Delete_QAVAB     [cluster=2];
Delete_CAFOR -- Delete_QAVAB     [weight=127];
Trigger_TOBAL    [cluster=3];
Delete_CAFOR -- Trigger_TOBAL    [weight=144];
.
.
.
```

I have around 80 clusters and many more nodes.
Any ideas on how I can add any style to these clusters? Preferably with one setting and not one for each node or cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `dot.exe` or an online service like
https://stamm-wilbrandt.de/GraphvizFiddle/.

Just use `node [cluster=-1,shape=box];` to change the shape of all nodes...